# ViewPropertyAnimator without start call, is there a difference?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, viewpropertyanimator

Sometimes I see code like

```
view.animate().alpha(1).start();
```

And sometimes

```
view.animate().alpha(1);
```

**What (if any) is the difference?**

The animation always starts but from my understanding of the source code two entirely different things happen in the background before it does so depending on the start call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void start ()
```

> Starts the currently pending property animations immediately. Calling
>   start() is optional because all animations start automatically at the
>   next opportunity. However, if the animations are needed to start
>   immediately and synchronously (not at the time when the next event is
>   processed by the hierarchy, which is when the animations would begin
>   otherwise), then this method can be used.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#start())

The only difference is that with start it starts immediately.

Comment: "Blinded by the white light" Cant believe I checked source code before checking the documentation for the method. Thanks Bojan!

Comment: It is always a good idea to see the docs when you meet a new method ^.^

Comment: What if you want to delay starting the animation _until_ you call `start()`?  How do you do that?